# How to know all data from the server synced to the tablet in SymmetricDS for Android?

Tags: java, android, symmetricds

I am using SymmetricDS tool for Syncing data between MySql database for Server and SQLite database for Android.i am done with fetching data from the server and sending data to the server with this tool. but i don't get any event for Syncing is started and Syncing is completed. with that i want to show progress dialog till all server data synced completely to my table.

i am not able to find something related to this in their documents over their website.please help me with this.i am working on this issue from last 4 days but could not able to find solution yet.

I have done this so far:

```
final String HELPER_KEY = "Key";
        Logger.e("TAG", "Key " + HELPER_KEY);
        SQLiteOpenHelperRegistry.register(HELPER_KEY, mDatabaseHelper);
        Intent intent = new Intent(c, SymmetricService.class);

        // Notify the service of the database helper key
        intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_SQLITEOPENHELPER_REGISTRY_KEY, HELPER_KEY);
        intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_REGISTRATION_URL, Constants.SYMMETRICDS_URL);
        intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_EXTERNAL_ID, node);
        intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_NODE_GROUP_ID, Constants.SYMMETRICDS_GROUP_ID);
        intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_START_IN_BACKGROUND, true);


        Properties properties = new Properties();
        // initial load existing notes from the Client to the Server
        properties.setProperty(ParameterConstants.ENGINE_NAME, node);

        properties.setProperty(ParameterConstants.AUTO_RELOAD_REVERSE_ENABLED, "true");
        intent.putExtra(SymmetricService.INTENTKEY_PROPERTIES, properties);
        c.startService(intent);
```

Comment: Can't you build a broadcast receiver filtering on this intent type :
`<intent-filter> <action android:name="org.jumpmind.symmetric.android.SymmetricService" />
</intent-filter>`
and debug to see what are the available values in the received value ?

Comment: how would i get sync start and completion event with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can run this SQL query:

```
SELECT sob.status, sob.node_id, COUNT(*) as cnt, 'outgoing' AS direction
FROM   SYM_OUTGOING_BATCH sob
GROUP BY sob.status, sob.node_id

UNION ALL

SELECT sob.status, sob.node_id, COUNT(*) as cnt, 'incoming' AS direction
FROM   SYM_INCOMING_BATCH sob
GROUP BY sob.status, sob.node_id
ORDER BY direction, sob.node_id, sob.status;
```